# Is there a method to control Apache Arrow Batch Sizes?

Tags: python, f#, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'd like to understand if there's a mechanism to control batch sizes being sent from server to client.

I've implemented the python server from the [Github repo](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/python/examples/flight) and a basic F# client.

As a test, I've added a flight containing 1 million rows which I'd like to send back to the client.
At first, the client fails with the following GRPC exception.

`One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode="ResourceExhausted", Detail="Received message exceeds the maximum configured message size."))`

As suggested, the message size has been exceeded. As a fix, I can set the maximum allowed grpc message size to be unlimited i.e.

```
let ops = new GrpcChannelOptions()
ops.MaxReceiveMessageSize <- Nullable()
let downloadChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(uri, ops)
let downloadClient = new FlightClient(download_channel)
```

However, I'd like to understand if there's a way to set the batch size being sent to the client from the server i.e. in the do_get method of the server

```
def do_get(self, context, ticket):
    key = ast.literal_eval(ticket.ticket.decode())
    if key not in self.flights:
        return None
    return pyarrow.flight.RecordBatchStream(self.flights[key])
```

I'd like to set the batch size when creating pyarrow.flight.RecordBatchStream. Looking at the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.flight.RecordBatchStream.html), the options specified using pyarrow.ipc.IpcWriteOptions doesn't allow the batch size to be set?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

**UPDATE** - see the accepted answer below which led me down the correct path. I've updated my code as follows to fix the issue.

```
def do_get(self, context, ticket):
    key = ast.literal_eval(ticket.ticket.decode())
    if key not in self.flights:
        return None
    reader = pyarrow.ipc.RecordBatchReader().from_batches(self.flights[key].schema, pyarrow.Table.to_batches(self.flights[key]))
    return pyarrow.flight.RecordBatchStream(reader)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `self.flights[key]` is a `pyarrow.Table`, you can re-chunk it ahead of time with [`Table.to_batches`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_batches). (This won't copy data, it'll just re-slice the underlying arrays.)

Note the size is in *rows*, which depending on the data type may not correspond well to *bytes*. This is an unfortunate mismatch. You can use [`get_total_buffer_size`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.RecordBatch.html#pyarrow.RecordBatch.get_total_buffer_size) to (cheaply) estimate the byte size and split batches further as needed (though if you have something like a single 4MB string, you're out of luck).

Comment: Your suggestion led me down the correct path - I've updated the original post with the correct code. Thank you!